# Windows Media Player library doesn't show any songs in folders!

Tags: windows-7, music, windows-media-player, libraries

I have Windows 7 Ultimate and have added my music folders to the library of Win Media Player, yet none of my songs appear in the library!
What shall I do?
Also, i have switched off many services, which are the services essential for the above to happen!

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean "added my music folder to the library of Win Media Player"?  Windows Media Player automatically searches your `Libraries` for media and does not have any "folders" of its own.

Your `Libraries` can be seen on the left side of the screen when you click `Documents` or `Computer` from the `Start` menu.

`Libraries` allow you to customize what folders are automatically searched for content.  For instance I do not use the `My Music` folder that Windows 7 provides under `C:\Users\Typoknig\My Music`, all of my music is stored on an external hard drive.

To account for this I had to right click `Music` under `Libraries` and select `Properties`.  There I was able to remove/add folders to automatically search for content.  You may need to do the same if you are not using the standard `My Music` folder.

Comment: did that, but doesn't work, the files don't appear in the library ...

Comment: @manishKungwani you can press `F5` to force an update.

Comment: even forcing the update doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Whilst inside Media Player, select Tools > Advanced > Restore Media Library. Allow it to close Media Player. Open it up again and see if it starts adding your music.